# Representation of Quaternion group in $GL(2,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am working with the representation of the quaternion group in $GL(2,3)$ generated by $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, C=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now $C=PBP^{-1}$ where $P= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  **I am trying to show that $A$ and $B$ are similar by an element in $GL(2,3)$.**

They are obviously similar in $GL(2,9)$ because they are both diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues:  Their characteristic polynomials are both $x^2+1$, and since its irreducible over $F_3$ and $F_3$ is perfect, the roots are distinct.

I feel that because of the relations $A=CB, B=AC, C=BA$,    $A$, $B$, $C$ should all "be on the same footing": $B$ and $C$ similar by P should mean that $A,B$ are similar too, without me having to worry about whether the similarity matrix has entries in $F_3$.  After all I should be able to use jacobi's identity and the matrix P to achieve this.  It has not been working out for some time!
edit:
another thing I am trying -
Probably the best way to do this is to look at all the embeddings of $Q_8 \hookrightarrow GL(2,3)$.

Comment: Their determinants are different so they can't be conjugate even over $GL(2, 9)$. The characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $x^{2} - 2$.

Comment: No they aren't.

Comment: In $Z/3$, the determinants of all these matrices is 1.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's right sorry. I was being dense.

Comment: If $\alpha \in F_9$ is a root of $x^2+1=0$ then the eigenvalues for each of the matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ are $-\alpha,\alpha$.  The explicit base change matrices that makes $A$, $B$ diagonal are $\pmatrix{ 1 & 1\cr \alpha & -\alpha \cr}$, $\pmatrix{ 1 & 1 \cr 1-\alpha & 1+\alpha}$

Comment: I was being really stupid. Finding the matrix is solving a bunch of linear equations. I've posted an answer. I hope my sleep deprivation hasn't caused me to make a mistake again.

Comment: thanks for getting me unstuck :)

Comment: user142843. In the comments the plainTeX matrix construction of `\pmatrix{ 1&1\cr \alpha&-\alpha\cr}` works. Don't ask me why :-) I took the liberty of editing your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to realize the outer automorphism $i\mapsto j\mapsto k\mapsto i$ of the quaternion group as an inner automorphism inside $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$.

Actually everything happens already inside $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$. This has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8=\langle A,B,C\rangle$. That automorphism is of order three, so we are looking for an element of order three. The first thing that comes to mind
$$
X=\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
happens to work. Namely,
it is easy to verify that
$$
XBX^{-1}=C,\qquad XCX^{-1}=A,\qquad\text{and}\qquad XAX^{-1}=B.
$$
This gives us a realization of $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$ as a semidirect product
$$
SL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)\cong Q_8\rtimes C_3.
$$

Comment: This is not very satisfactory. Somehow in $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$ conjugation by an element of order three gives a "handedness preserving" automorphism of $Q_8$. There really should be a better explanation for this!

Comment: One explanation is that ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ is isomorphic to the group of units of the Hurwitz quaternions: there are $24$ Hurwitz quaternions $u$ with $N(u) =1,$ and these obviously form a group. Its elements are $\pm 1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k$ togther with all $16$ possibilities for $\frac{\pm 1 \pm i \pm j \pm k}{2}$, giving a group of order $24$. The usual quaternion subgroup of order $8$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Very nice, @Geoff!

Comment: The connection to units of quaternionic orders shows up elsewhere. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/278798/11619) the same group appears as a group of isomorphisms of an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 3):

It's a general fact that if two $n \times n$ matrices with entries in a field $F$ are similar over a field $K$ containing $F,$ they are already similar over $F.$ This is a consequence of the theory of the rational canonical form (which reduces to the Jordan normal form when the field is algebraically closed). What happens in this example is a rather more straightforward than usual of the general theory. Both $A$ and $B$ have minimal (and characteristic) polynomial $x^{2}+1.$ Now when $M$ is any matrix with this minimum polynomial, we can find a vector $v$ such that $\{v,Mv\}$ is linearly independent, so a basis. With respect to the basis $\{v,Mv \}$ we see that (the linear transformation represented by $M$ in the old basis) has matrix $\left(\begin{array}{clcr} 0 & -1\\1& 0\end{array} \right)$. Hence $TMT^{-1} =\left(\begin{array}{clcr} 0 & -1\\1& 0\end{array} \right)$ for some $T \in {\rm GL}(2,3),$ where $T$ is a change of basis matrix. This shows that any $3 \times 3$ matrix with entries in ${\rm GF}(3)$ and minimum polynomial $x^{2}+1$
is conjugate to $A$ within ${\rm GL}(2,3)$. Since $B$ also has characteristic (and minimum) polynomial $x^{2}+1,$ it is true that $A$ and $B$ are conjugate within ${\rm GL}(2,3).$

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose they are conjugate by

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
x & y\\
z & w \end{array} \right).$$

Then, we have

$$MB = AM \Rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{rr}
x + y & x - y\\
z+w & z-w \end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
-z & -w\\
x & y \end{array} \right).$$

So, $z = -x- y, w = y - x$ and putting these into the last two equations gives

$$x = x, y = y$$

and hence we can choose arbitrary values of $x$ and $y$. So define $M$ as

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0\\
-1 & -1 \end{array} \right).$$

Just for confirmation,

$$MB = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

and

$$AM =\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right).$$